# Why won't pg_basebackup output go to log?

Tags: postgresql, scripting

I run a nightly pg_basebackup from a cron job (Postgres 9.3 on debian "wheezy"), but the backup has been failing. It actually creates output, but the .tar file is corrupt and won't extract. I went to my log file, only to find it is 0 bytes. Could anybody tell me what is wrong with my setup? Why isn't the log file saving the output of pg_basebackup?

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
export PATH

BASEBACKUP_LOG=/var/log/postgresql/basebackup.log
[ -f $BASEBACKUP_LOG ] && mv -f $BASEBACKUP_LOG $BASEBACKUP_LOG.old

BACKUP_PATH=/path/to/backup/$(date +%F)
pg_basebackup -D $BACKUP_PATH -Ft -z -v 2>&1 | ts '%F %T %Z' &> $BASEBACKUP_LOG
```

The way I'm reading the pg_basebackup line, I think it should redirect stderr to stdout, pipe the combined stream to the ts function (prepend timestamp to a line) and write that to the path at $BASEBACKUP_LOG. Am I missing something obvious here?

On advice given below, I added an explicit reference to the path for ts & pg_basebackup (both reside in /usr/bin). There was no change in behavior.

Comment: Look at your cron logs. Is `pg_basebackup` on the `PATH`? is `ts`?

Comment: The only thing in the cron log is a single entry showing that the script is called. The cron is under the postgres user, which darn sure better have access to pg_basebackup. But again, the backup runs, it just doesn't work. I need to see the output to find out why.

Comment: Oh, if I run echo '' | ts '%F %T %Z'
as the postgres user I see the timestamp, so ts seems to be reachable by that user.

Comment: cron overrides the `PATH`. It's a different envirionment and has nothing to do with what user is running. Please read "man cron" for more information.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right about the path. Other crons under pg user have no problem with ts, though, so I don't think that's it. And pg_basebackup runs, so that's not it either. I don't think it's a path problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified `#!/bin/sh` in your script's shabang line. This gives you a POSIX shell. Under POSIX style shells you can only specify numbers for redirection, as noted in the documentation under section [2.7 Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).

`&>` is a "bashism", shown here in the bash documentation under [io-redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

This can cause undefined behavior under POSIX compliant shells acting as `/bin/sh`, and by running `shellcheck -s sh` on the contents of the script in the above question, as stated under the warning for [SC2039](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2039), which warns that `&>` is non-standard, and might fail under different contexts.

You might have better luck, if you specify `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or if you change the way that you're doing the redirection, if you want to keep using the `#!/bin/sh` shell.

As for the `$BACKUP_PATH`, you might want to double-quote it to prevent any sort of weirdnesses with globbing or word splitting that can happen, which could also possibly explain the zero size tar file.

Hope that helps. =)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

Find out exactly where pg_basebackup is

```
#> which pg_basebackup
```

Then add in the full paths in your cron job

```
BACKUP_PATH=/path/to/backup/$(date +%F)
/path/to/pg_basebackup/pg_basebackup -D $BACKUP_PATH -Ft -z -v 2>&1 | ts '%F %T %Z' &> $BASEBACKUP_LOG
```

Cron needs the full path to execute commands in the correct context.

**Update**

Not sure if this will help you. Here is the backup command I typically used to backup a database.

usr/local/bin/pg_dump -Ft -c -p some_port -U username -h HOST database_name | gzip -9 > SOME_FILE

***Keep in mind the following when using pg_dump***

1. If you backup with pg_dump (using other than the 'plain' format, ie. -Fp, which is the default) , you must restore the file with [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html)
2. The version of [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) must be newer or equivalent to the version of the server you are backing up.

Comment: I'll give that a try, but I'm a bit confused why that would affect the log output. The pg_basebackup does execute as seen by the (invalid) backup file that's created.

Comment: Hello @Phil, updated my answer